# GIT - How to create a new branch to refactor an entire project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have an ios project that i would like to restart from scratch. I want to do that into a new branch from the git repo. I don't really know how to proceed.
I've created the new branch and a new project in xcode. But now i would like to version the new project in my new branch.

Thanks!

Comment: Beyond XCode mechanics, you would be well served to understand how branch and merging works: http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xcode for that, simply go to `Source Control/Check Out...` choose your new branch and then `Source Control/Commit...` your changes and `Source Control/Push...` and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Clone your repo. Then reset your HEAD to the commit you want to start from now create new branch and push it to remote..

e.g

```
 git clone project

 git reset --hard CommitID

 git checkout -b newbranch

 git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/newbranch
```